# What is the meaning of "support propre"?

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, translation-request, mathematical-french

At the top of page 278 in Deligne's [Weil I paper](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number23.pdf), he refers to the cohomology group $H_c^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ as having "support propre". This literally translates to "proper support", but in context it looks like it should be "compact support". Is that what "propre" means here?

Comment: I don't think that's right because Deligne wrote an appendix to Hartshorne's "Residues and Duality" titled "[Cohomologie à support propre et construction du foncteur $f^{!}$](https://publications.ias.edu/node/348)". I'm not 100% sure he's talking about the same cohomology there as I didn't read the article, but it seems that "support propre" can be used as a standalone phrase in this context. Also, I've seen the $H_c$ notation used to indicate compact support in the context of cohomology, for example [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_with_compact_support).

Comment: You're probably right then. Again I know very little sheaf cohomology -- it was just an idea based on the stand-alone sentence. I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: Compare the definition [here](http://fabrice.orgogozo.perso.math.cnrs.fr/SGA4/originaux/SGA4-XVIIo.pdf#page=54) (French), with the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_cohomology#Poincar%C3%A9_duality_and_cohomology_with_compact_support) (English). Same definition. Oh, you added the same links. Yes, it is the same definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice he has already used the adjective "propre" several times on pages 274 and 275 to refer to a property of a variety, ("propre et lisse").  since I believe a complex variety is compact (in the complex analytic topology) if and only if it is "complete" if and only if the map to the one point spectrum of the field is a proper map, I think you are right that he is using proper as a synonym for complete or compact.

See Mumford's redbook chapter I.10,Th. 2, and Hartshorne chapter II.4, definition top of p.105.

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up.